# C# Gridview to Excel with number formatting and table line

Tags: c#, excel, formatting

Hello I want import my data in Gridview to Excel, my data in Gridview is "00, 02, 04" but in excel my data change to "0, 2, 4" I dont wont it, i want my data in Excel like same in Gridview.And How to move rows to new columns, for exp i have 160 rows data, i want in excel split to 3 columns, 1 column have 40 rows. This my code :

```
private void exToExcel()
    {
        if (RekapdataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            //XcelApp.Cells[5,2].NumberFormat = "00";
            XcelApp.Cells[1, 1] = "Tanggal";
            XcelApp.Cells[1, 2] = labelTglRekap.Text;
            XcelApp.Cells[2, 1] = "Kode Pemain";
            XcelApp.Cells[2, 2] = labelKodePemain.Text;
            XcelApp.Cells[4, 1] = "No";
            int x = RekapdataGridView.RowCount;
            for (int y = 1; y <= RekapdataGridView.RowCount; y++)
            {
                XcelApp.Cells[4+y, 1] = y;
            }

            for (int i = 2; i < RekapdataGridView.Columns.Count + 2; i++)
            {
                XcelApp.Cells[4, i] = RekapdataGridView.Columns[i - 2].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < RekapdataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < RekapdataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    XcelApp.Cells[i + 5, j + 2] =string.Format("{0:00}", RekapdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value); 
                }
            }
            XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();

            XcelApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

This is my data in excel :

[image]

I want my data can showing like this image :
[image]

Sorry if my English is bad, i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had it with

```
XcelApp.Cells[5,2].NumberFormat = "00";
```

Just change it to

```
XcelApp.Cells[5,2].NumberFormat = "@";
```

Which will make the cell format be 'Text' instead of number. Excel always tries to simplify numbers from my experience.

Just don't forget to do it to ALL cells you are writing into.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i use that, all rows value is 00:00

Comment: I fix string format with string.Format("'{0}", ... );

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end :)

Comment: Do you know how to move my data to cell C after 40 rows, move to cell E after 80 rows ?

Comment: Create a variable that counts the rows as you iterate through them and when that variable reaches 40 change the column to C and at 80 change the column to E
`int column = 0;
for (int y = 1; y <= RekapdataGridView.RowCount; y++)
            {
              if(y == 40)
                         column = 2;
              else if(y == 80)
                         column = 4;
              else
                         column = 0;
                XcelApp.Cells[4+y, column] = y;
            }`